SSRS Sub Report to Excel creates Blank Row
I am trying to create a report where we can dynamically increase the column width while still retaining it as one column when exporting.
I have a Sub-Report that I pass the Data to and a value of how many Columns I want to see merged.
My issue is when I export to excel it creates an extra column and I cannot figure out why
I tried keeping the text together but every time I add the sub report I have this issue, everything aligns perfectly as it should as well.
Note this table is on its own Sheet so tables around it should not affect this column
[Main Report](https://i.sstatic.net/77OT0teK.png)
[Sub Report](https://i.sstatic.net/gA4tVmIz.png)
[Excel Export](https://i.sstatic.net/7WxIMPeK.png)


It's hard to tell because the columns are blurred but in the Main report there's a text box above the green arrow that doesn't align with the column that the arrow points at. The difference between these two would create a hidden column. Make the text box a little wider so it aligns with the column.

Could there be an embedded delimiter within a field.
I've had a tab character in one cell that caused an extra column in the output

@HannoverFist, there is a page break before and after this Tablix so the textbox above should not affect it. I will try your suggestion and see if it helps though
